# How can I unregister a service registered with NsdManager?

Tags: android

I am trying to clean up properly a service registered with

```
myNsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, myRegistrationListener)
```

I do call

```
myNsdManager.unregisterService(myRegistrationListener);
```

in onDestroy(), but the problem is that when I recompile my app in Eclipse, it reinstalls the app by closing the previously running instance without calling the onDestroy(), leaving my previous registered service still registered and getting discovered by myNsdManager.discoverServices(). How can I properly unregister my previous service? I did search google but no answer yet.

Thank you

Comment: Unregister in `onStop` instead of `onDestroy`.

Comment: Doesn't work eighter, it did not unregister. Also it seems no onPause, onStop, onDestry method is called when uninstalling an app from Eclipse at least

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @user1804542 Were you able to fix it?